# Comparar valores de dois arrays e gerar um terceiro com os valores únicos javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo, com google script, um sistema bem simples que monitora o andamento de atividades do dia a dia, tenho uma tabela com as atividades solicitadas, uma tabela com as interações e uma tabela com o status (aberto ou fechado). preciso comparar a lista com os ID's da atividades solicitadas com a lista com os ID's da atividades fechadas. Os ID's que sobrarem eu assumo que estão abertos.
Obs.: sou iniciante em programação, podem me corrigir a vontade!

```js
function arrayabertas(){
var todos = [08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528];
var fechado = [8072020104528];
var abertos = [];

// Verifica se cada número jogado
// está na lista dos sorteados
for(var i=0; i<fechado.length; i++) {
    if(todos.indexOf(fechado[i]) > -1) {
        abertos.push(fechado[i]);
    }
}
    return(abertos);
}
```

Comment: Júlio, vc não pode ficar mudando a pergunta porque isso invalida as respostas já existentes. Se tem outra pergunta, por favor [faça-a aqui](/questions/ask). E eu sugiro que nessa nova pergunta vc coloque um exemplo da planilha para que as pessoas possam testar (pois [só com imagens não dá](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052))

Comment: E se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema (o problema específico que está na sua pergunta, da forma que vc colocou, não o problema da planilha), vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Não leve a mal, é que a ideia do site é ter um problema específico por pergunta. Se tiver outra pergunta (mesmo que esteja relacionada), então o ideal é fazer outra. Ficar mudando a pergunta   vai contra a ideia do site e deixa-o mais desorganizado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1684/112052

Comment: Ok, tudo bem, eu agradeço pelos comentários e ajuda, eu ainda sou iniciante nisso, vou me atentar na forma de usar o site, obrigaduuu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se já estiver usando ambientes compatíveis com [ECMAScript 2015](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), uma alternativa é usar [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), que já possui [bom suporte dos browsers atuais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility).

O `Set` garante que os elementos dele serão únicos (que é um dos seus requisitos), e também possui algumas operações que facilitam o algoritmo para o que você precisa (além de ser mais eficiente, como veremos ao final).

Por exemplo, para o seu caso, bastaria criar um `Set` com todos os valores e ir removendo os que estão fechados. O que sobrar são os itens abertos:

```js
let todos = [ 08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528 ];
let fechado = [ 8072020104528 ];

let abertos = new Set(todos);
for (let e of fechado) { // remove todos os fechados
    abertos.delete(e);
}

// converter para array
abertos = Array.from(abertos);
console.log(abertos);
```

---

As outras respostas sugerem usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ou [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), que de fato funcionam (exceto que com `includes` você deveria verificar quais elementos **não** estão em `fechado`, ou seja, `abertos = todos.filter(x => ! fechado.includes(x))`), mas são mais ineficientes porque tanto `indexOf` quanto `includes` percorrem o array `todos` desde o início.

Ou seja, para cada elemento de `fechado`, você tem que percorrer o array `todos` desde o início, até encontrar o elemento. E quando você percorre o mesmo array várias e várias vezes, está criando uma variação do chamado [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/), que é extremamente ineficiente.

Claro que para arrays pequenos - como é o seu caso - a diferença será insignificante e talvez isso não passe de micro-otimização. Mas para arrays maiores [a diferença é significativa](https://jsperf.com/set-vs-indexof-vs-includes/1).

Obviamente que, se isso for rodar em browsers antigos que não suportam `Set`, aí o jeito é usar `indexOf` ou `includes` mesmo.

---

Outro detalhe é que, se você está usando uma função para verificar os itens abertos, é interessante receber os arrays `todos` e `fechado` como parâmetros, pois assim a função fica mais genérica e reusável, podendo receber quaisquer arrays (da forma que você fez, ela só funciona para os arrays informados). Ficaria assim:

```js
function verificarAbertos(todos, fechado){
    let abertos = new Set(todos);
    for (let e of fechado) {
        abertos.delete(e);
    }
    
    // converter para array
    return Array.from(abertos);
}

let todos = [08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528];
let fechado = [8072020104528];
let abertos = verificarAbertos(todos, fechado);
console.log(abertos);

// posso passar outros arrays também
console.log(verificarAbertos([1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5])); // [1, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) com [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains), onde esse filtro só será satisfatório quando tiver contido o valor testado, ***exemplo***:

```js
var todos = [08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528];
var fechado = [8072020104528];
var abertos = todos.filter(x => fechado.includes(x)); 

console.log(abertos);
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
- [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

Comment: A resposta mais simples e pratica sem fazer muito malabarismo com os arrays, única coisa pra ajustar seria negar `fechado.includes(x)` visto que `abertos` deve conter os elementos que não existem em `fechado`, de resto perfeito.

Answer (score 1):

Seu algoritmo está errado, ele verifica quais elementos em `todos` também estão em fechados, quando na verdade deveria verificar quais NÃO estão em fechados.

```js
function arrayabertas(){
  var todos = [08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528];
  var fechado = [8072020104528];
  var abertos = [];

  // Verifica se cada número jogado
  // está na lista dos sorteados
  for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
    // verifica qual em "todos" não está fechado
    if(fechado.indexOf(todos[i]) === -1) {
      abertos.push(todos[i]);
    }
  }
  return(abertos);
}
```

Você pode utilizar a função `filter` para o código ficar mais limpo

```js
function arrayabertas(){
  var todos = [08072020105842, 08072020110953, 8072020104528];
  var fechado = [8072020104528];
  var abertos = [];

  abertos = todos.filter((x) => fechado.indexOf(x) === -1)

  return(abertos);
}
```